# using xpath in php wrong number of result

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am new to XPATH and PHP. I am trying to achieve a user validation with the help of XPATH in PHP. My data is in xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<customers>
    <customer>
        <id>1</id>
        <fName>sa</fName>
        <lastName>aa</lastName>
        <email>a@a.com</email>
        <password>a</password>
    </customer> 
    <customer>
        <id>2</id>
        <fName>bb</fName>
        <lastName>cc</lastName>
        <email>b@b.com</email>
        <password>b</password>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

My php code snippet is

```
if(file_exists('customer.xml'))
        {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->load('customer.xml');

            $xpathvar = new Domxpath($doc);

            //check if user exists and password matches
            $queryResult = $xpathvar->query("customers/customer[email= '".$userEmail."' and password= '".$password."']");

            var_dump($queryResult);
            if(count($queryResult)== 1)
            {
                //successful login
                echo "great";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Invalid email address or password";
            }
        }
```

No matter what input I provide, `count($queryResult)` returns 1.
Not sure why the correct matching is not done.

When I provide `$userEmail="a@a.com"` and the `$password="a"` the `var_dump($queryResult);` gives the following output

```
object(DOMNodeList)[3]
  public 'length' => int 0
```

Comment: its a typo. Corrected, thanks. Does it make any difference in using DomDocument or SimpleXML? I am not sure, I have used what I found first.

Comment: i've updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$queryResult is DOMNodeList object which property length is amount of found nodes. Test result using :

```
if ($queryResult->length == 1)
```

And change your Xpath because it don't see the root eelement:

```
customer[email= '".$userEmail."' and password= '".$password."']
```

[see demo](https://eval.in/571815)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code snippet to this

```
if(file_exists('customer.xml'))
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('customer.xml');

    $xpathvar = new Domxpath($doc);

    //check if user exists and password matches
    $queryResult = $xpathvar->query("/customers/customer[email= '".$userEmail."' and password= '".$password."']");

    if($queryResult->length == 1)
    {
        //successful login
        echo "great";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid email address or password";
    }
}
```

Where

```
$queryResult->length is the number of all nodes that satisfy to the query
```

also put /-Slash on the begining of the query

```
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query("/customers/customer[email= '".$userEmail."' and password= '".$password."']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the password itself in the XML, but a hash. So to fetch the password from the XML file you use an expression, but verify it using a PHP function.

You can generate the hash using the `password_hash()` method:

```
var_dump(password_hash('a', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

Output:

```
string(60) "$2y$10$o.aLdT4.xF6DaSaZAE4/8./omHnN5p3hBpfgzxSRwnXwdcfR27ova"
```

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` supports Xpath expressions that return scalar values. So it is possible to cast the node list into a string directly. It will return an empty string if the node list was empty.

```
$userEmail = 'a@a.com';
$password = 'a';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$userPasswordHash = $xpath->evaluate(
  sprintf(
    'string(/customers/customer[email = %s]/password)',
    quoteXpathLiteral($userEmail)
  )
);

$isValid = (
  $userPasswordHash  != '' &&   
  password_verify($password, $userPasswordHash)
);

var_dump($isValid);
```

You might notice that I used a function to quote the $userEmail value. This avoids an Xpath injection. Imagine someone provides a $userEmail value like `"" or true()`. Xpath 1.0 has no escaping it just disallows single quotes in double quoted strings and double quotes in single quoted strings. Here is the function.

```
public function quoteXpathLiteral($string) {
  $string = str_replace("\x00", '', $string);
  $hasSingleQuote = FALSE !== strpos($string, "'");
  if ($hasSingleQuote) {
    $hasDoubleQuote = FALSE !== strpos($string, '"');
    if ($hasDoubleQuote) {
      $result = '';
      preg_match_all('("[^\']*|[^"]+)', $string, $matches);
      foreach ($matches[0] as $part) {
        $quoteChar = (substr($part, 0, 1) == '"') ? "'" : '"';
        $result .= ", ".$quoteChar.$part.$quoteChar;
      }
      return 'concat('.substr($result, 2).')';
    } else {
      return '"'.$string.'"';
    }
  } else {
    return "'".$string."'";
  }
}
```